# how to input updating DataFrame into sql or db in real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I've already  implemented what I want logic as DataFrame

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/pythonfile/lecture2.py", line 67, in OnReceiveReal_time_Data
    cur.execute("UPDATE expriment SET "women"='SUM' WHERE rowid=count2 + 1;") # it doesn's work I don't know why really
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "=": syntax error
pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.

Comment: I'll wait for anyone answer

Comment: @Mayeul sgc I edited my question here is error message

Comment: try `"UPDATE expriment SET "+women+"='SUM' WHERE rowid=count2 + 1;"` and same for men, add the `+`

Comment: @Mayeul sgc NameError: name 'women' is not defined-> this error message happened but the DB already has women columns when it started. I don't understand what is mean it doesn't defined?

Comment: ah, I thought women was a variable. In that case try `cursor.execute("UPDATE expriment SET women='SUM' WHERE rowid=?;",count2+1)`

Comment: @Mayeul sgc "women" is columns name. "count2" and "sum" both are an integer variable. but sill thanks the answer

Comment: if sum is an integer variable then `cursor.execute("UPDATE expriment SET women=? WHERE rowid=?;",(SUM,count2+1))`

Comment: @ Mayeul sgc I wrote this and its result
cur.execute("UPDATE expriment SET women='sum' WHERE rowid=?;",count2+1)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: that is because in your request here 'sum' is considered a string, see my answer just above

Comment: @Mayeul sgc It works thanks. I really owe you my best thanks

Comment: great, i'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the bad request formatting.

```py
cursor.execute("UPDATE expriment SET women=? WHERE rowid=?;",(SUM,count2+1))
```

Here we take the variables out of the request to properly assign them. Otherwise SQL is taking it as text

Comment: hi, I have some additional question. I got a problem that  ///   cur.execute("UPDATE expriment5 SET m=? WHERE rowid=?;",(SUM5,fivthcount2+1))
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database///
by using this code. actually, I'm running a couple of additional line to collect much information separately each of them into several table in one table.
why permission errors come?

Comment: if you need more reputation, I can ask more and i'll give that link in this website.
please more help me

Comment: Check your database settings I guess, this is another question you should create a new post about it